# No appreciation at work

Tags: united-states, appraisal

I have been observing a strange phenomenon at work. Practically speaking, I am the ONLY working member of a large project. I wrote almost all the programs by myself. However, the “project manager” did/does not show any task assignment against my name in the task tracking software so far (This means officially I am/have been doing nothing!)

What should I do about this problem? Should I take this up with my manager? He is a nice person (and also the manager of the “project manager”). Please advise.

Regards,

Comment: Take it up with your nice manager.

Comment: Did you ask the PM why your name was not showing next to tasks you are doing?

Comment: Whose name is showing up instead of yours? What is that person doing instead? Why are you doing their work for them?

Answer (score 4):

> Should I take this up with my manager?

Yes, unless you can assign to yourself tasks which you are doing, in which case, just fix it yourself. This is unlikely to be major issue of worry unless the company is very reliant on its issue-tracking tool for performance management (in which case it's essential that it's preceded by a culture of using the issue-tracker properly).

It should not be just a matter of recognition (if at all!) - accurate task assignment avoids the situation where multiple people are working on things at once (or nobody is).